# How do I explode a dataset with flatmap?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatmap

I have a sequence of a case class, which has a String followed by a sequence of Strings. How do I flatmap the sequence of Strings (second column) without losing the first column?

I tried this:

`flatmap(_.second)`

But in this case I lose the first column.

Here is my code:

```
case class A(
            first:String,
            second:Seq[String]
            )

val ds = Seq(
  A("1", Seq("A","B")),
  A("2",  Seq("C"))
) toDS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of exploding your second col and keep the first col is effectively `flatMap` :

```
ds.flatMap{ case A(a,b) => b.map((a,_)) }
```

should output :

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  A|
|  1|  B|
|  2|  C|
+---+---+
```